# Does symfony overwrire max_execution_time for its tasks?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, symfony-1.4

In my php.ini, max_execution_time is set as 30 and for cli, its 0.

Whenever I execute my php script through cli, I get that max_execution_time is set as 0 correctly. but whenever I execute my symfony task, I get max_execution_time as 1200.

I checked that I have not reset max_execution_time anywhere in my application. It seems that symfony is overwriting max_execution_time.

If anyone has any idea how can I resolve the problem as whenever I execute my symfony task, it gets failed whenever its execution time exceeds to 1200.

Symfony version: 1.4

php version: 5.4.19

OS: Fedora 19

Code sample:

Symfony task:

```
    <?php
    class sampleTask extends sfBaseTask
    {
        protected function configure()
        {
            $this->namespace           = 'cron';
            $this->name                = 'sample';
    EOF;
        }
        protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
        {
            echo ini_get('max_execution_time');die;
        }
    }
    ?>

  On executing php symfony cron:sample, it prints 1200.
```

php script:

```
    <?php
        echo ini_get('max_execution_time');
    ?>

  On execution php sample.php, it prints 0.
```

Comment: It looks to me like [Symfony 1.4 specifically sets the time limit to unlimited for command-line tasks](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/75d9b19c845d29f6d1809d5bfc9b31d27cc489b6/lib/command/sfCommandApplication.class.php#L545)...

Comment: (Are you sure you're using the same PHP version in both cases? Do you get any clues from running `phpinfo()` in both cases?)

Comment: @MattGibson, Yes! I have single php installed on my machine. On executing symfony task, php info is giving max_execution_time => 1200 => 0, On executing php script, its giving max_execution_time => 0 => 0.